# How to split comma-separated values in random order and create variables for each unique vlaue in R?

Tags: r, sorting, split

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
ID   Tags
------------
1    a,b,c
2    d,a,e
3    e,a
```

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
ID   Tag.a  Tag.b   Tag.c   Tag.d   Tag.e
-----------------------------------------
1     1       1       1       0       0
2     1       0       0       1       1
3     1       0       0       0       1
```

I tried the separate function from tidyverse but I don't know how to deal with the random order of the tags...and I am relatively new to R, so I would really appreciate some kind help with this. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `cSplit_e`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(df1, "Tags", type = "character", sep=",", fill = 0, drop = TRUE)
#   ID Tags_a Tags_b Tags_c Tags_d Tags_e
#1:  1      1      1      1      0      0
#2:  2      1      0      0      1      1
#3:  3      1      0      0      0      1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Tags = c("a,b,c", "d,a,e", "e,a")), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```